# Javascript/jQuery find and delete array value in the rest of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok, not sure how to ask this question, but I'm trying to gather values into an array, but each value MAY have duplicated (or appended) strings on the rest of the values and I believe they are always built on top of each other...

Here's what I mean.

if I were to output an array, it would be something like this:

```
[0] => This is a string.
[1] => here's another string. This is a string.
[2] => And now there's a third string.  here's another string. This is a string.
[3] => Here's a string that might not follow the pattern.  This is a string.
```

What I'd like to finally output is

```
[0] => This is a string.
[1] => here's another string.
[2] => And now there's a third string.
[3] => Here's a string that might not follow the pattern.
```

Basically, Any string can not have duplicated text in any other string.

Not sure if I'm making sense.

EDIT:

Here's the full story - I'm gathering emails through PHP IMAP with an AJAX script.  I've gotten the text of the body from each email, but unfortunately, there's no way to find the quoted text through all email services.  So what I've done is make each email body show and I've gotten rid of any extra characters (like line quote >> characters).

What I want to do now is: starting with the first email, check the other emails, and remove the first string if it's in there, then use the second email, check the rest of the emails and remove that string, and so on.

It's not perfect, but it will shorten a lot of the messages.

Comment: Double for loop with `indexOf` check. Depending on the input the output may get very broken. Maybe it makes sense in your case, it seems very strange to me.

Comment: can you provide your data source where you are gathering your values

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, I've added an explanation of the source.

Comment: @Halcyon, I'll see what I can do with a double for loop.  I'm going to stumble a while on it

Comment: you want only to get 1 sentence in each string? if i understand it correctly

Comment: @roullie, I've added a bit more back-story.  There can possibly be many paragraphs in a single string, but I want to make sure that; that specific array value does not show in any other array value

Comment: I don't think your approach will work for your email matching problem. Why not just remove any quoted text? (ie. lines starting with `>`). Why is it important that you remove parts of the email body?

Comment: if you want in jQuery try this.  http://jsfiddle.net/roullie666/bzcpoemx/

Comment: You should accept one of these answers, or explain why you can't so they can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

This builds a new array using each string in the old array after first replacing, in that string, each string in the new array with empty string.

```js
var arr = [
  'This is a string.',
  "here's another string. This is a string.",
  "And now there's a third string.  here's another string. This is a string.",
  "Here's a string that might not follow the pattern.  This is a string."
];

var out = arr.reduce(function(w, s) {
  w.push(w.reduce(function(s1, e) {
    return s1.replace(e, "");
  }, s).trim());
  return w;
}, []);

alert(out);
```

Comment: This is how you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var strings = [
    "This is a string.",
    "here's another string. This is a string.",
    "And now there's a third string.  here's another string. This is a string.",
    "Here's a string that might not follow the pattern.  This is a string."
];

var i, j, pos;
for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i += 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < strings.length; j += 1) {
        if (i === j) {
            continue;
        }
        pos = strings[i].indexOf(strings[j]);
        if (pos !== -1) {
            strings[i] = strings[i].substr(0, pos) + strings[i].substr(pos + strings[j].length);
        } 
    }
}

console.log(strings);
output: [
  "This is a string.",
  "here's another string. ",
  "And now there's a third string.  ",
  "Here's a string that might not follow the pattern.  "
];
```

Note that this code doesn't replace multiple occurances. If you want that, add a while-loop.

Comment: nice answer! One thing through, can you trim result?

Comment: Sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
This will cause problems if the string has special regex chars. A JS global repalce without regex can exploit `split` and `join`, (http://www.adequatelygood.com/JS-Find-and-Replace-with-SplitJoin.html) see below:

<strike>Javascript requires a regex to do a global replace, so something like this</strike>

```
var arr = [
    'This is a string.',
    "here's another string. This is a string.",
    "And now there's a third string.  here's another string. This is a string.",
    "Here's a string that might not follow the pattern.  This is a string."
];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (j !== i) {
            arr[i] = arr[i].split(arr[j]).join("");
        }
    }
}
console.log(arr);


[
"This is a string.", 
"here's another string.",
"And now there's a third string.",
"Here's a string that might not follow the pattern."
]
```

It should replace all occurences

Comment: This is sort of working.  I will sometimes get an error that says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /string/: Unmatched ')'`.  I will look into this, because other times this works just fine

Comment: @ntgCleaner see edit, I forgot that if your string has any special characters in it, it might generate an invalid regex. using split/join solves that

Answer (score 0):

use like following. Use .map function of jquery to iterate over the array. the code given as following

```
var arr = [
           'This is a string.',
           "here's another string. This is a string.",
           "And now there's a third string.  here's another string. This is a string.",
           "Here's a string that might not follow the pattern.  This is a string."
         ];

     var out=$.map(arr,function (i,v){
         return i.substr(0,i.indexOf(".") + 1);
     });
     console.log("value is"+out);
```

Comment: That looks for periods and deletes everything after them.  What if string1 was "this.is.a.test"?