# jQuery find and delete string in array using same array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, email

I asked this question: [Javascript/jQuery find and delete array value in the rest of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685425/javascript-jquery-find-and-delete-array-value-in-the-rest-of-array/33687906#33687906), but I feel like I explained it wrong.  Here's my second try.

I am pulling emails using PHP's imap functions.  I am able to successfully pull the emails.  Below is a snippet of the code to show how it may be encoded.

```
foreach($all_email_dates as $email){
    $email_id = explode(":", $email);
    $email_id = $email_id[1];
    $email = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 1.1, FT_UID);
    if($email == "") $email = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 1, FT_UID);
    if(imap_base64($email)) $email = imap_base64($email);
    $email = quoted_printable_decode($email);
    $email = preg_replace('/(^\w.+:\n)?(^>.*(\n|$))+/mi', '', $email);
    array_push($emails, $email);
    echo $email;
    echo "<:>";
}
```

This pulls all of the emails I need and puts them in chronological order.

Now, I grab them using an AJAX call and try to manipulate them here:

```
$.post('php/contacts-get-email.php', {email:email}, function(data) {
    var email_body = data.split("<:>"); //Puts each email into an array
    console.log(email_body);
    //I have test code here for now that is not working
});
```

What I'd like to do is iterate through that array (`email_body`) and find and delete any duplicate strings.  The output from above is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/exdjumqm/.  (I put it in a fiddle instead of here because it would get too long to show here) ---**ADD** Here's a JSON file to play with too: http://412webdesigns.com/uploads/emails.json

**The main goal** is to delete any text that has previously been in an email.  If possible, I would like to keep the carriage returns for formatting purposes.

For example, the first email has a paragraph of text that shows up in emails 2 and 4.  I would like that text deleted.  But I'm not sure where to go from here.

If you need any more details, please let me know.  Thank you

**UPDATE**
Here are the email strings pasted here:

First email

```
Thanks so much name! We had a great time today too and can't wait to 
see\r\nwhat the pictures look like! Looking forward to seeing them when you're 
all\r\ndone editing! Thanks again :)\r\n
```

Second email

```
Hi name!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThank you for the email! You don't have to wait any 
further!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nWe were able to get around 70 pictures that we think 
were noteworthy! To  \r\ndownload ALL of your pictures, head to 
www.site.com\/download  \r\nand use the password \"AN5k9W\". This should 
automatically start your  \r\ndownload, so check your downloads folder. It's a 
half of a gig, so the file  \r\nis pretty large!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTo check out 
some of the pics while you're waiting on the download, head to  
\r\nhttp:\/\/site.com\/#\/151108-name_name-engagement or  
\r\nfacebook.com\/site. Remember to like us and share your pics  \r\nwith 
anyone you want!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nLet us know what you think!\r\n\r\nWe look 
forward to henameng from you!\r\n\r\nname & name\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nOn Sun, Nov 8, 
2015 at 2:52 PM name name <name@gmail.com>  \r\nwrote:\r\n\r\n\r\nThanks so 
much name! We had a great time today too and can't wait to see  \r\nwhat the 
pictures look like! Looking forward to seeing them when you're all  \r\ndone 
editing! Thanks again :)\r\n
```

You'll notice the second email contains the first email since it is a reply to the first one.

Comment: you'd like to delete text that has previously been in an email. by 'text', do you mean, sentences? (or words?)

Comment: also, could you provide a '.json' file that could be worked with?

Comment: @VineethRaj sentences, paragraphs.  If you take a look at the fiddle above, You'll see the first email is a paragraph of sentences.  In the second email, at the bottom, you'll see that same paragraph repeated again.  I'd like the first email to be removed from the second (and fourth) email.

Comment: @VineethRaj, I'll try to make a json file from the PHP page

Comment: okay, i'll try to whip up a function in jQuery.

Comment: the 'first' occourence needs to be preserved, right?

Comment: @VineethRaj, Correct.

Comment: I've added a JSON file in the description above

Answer (score 1):

```
var formatted_email_body = []; // Init a blank array
var email_body = data.split("<:>");

for(var i=0; i<email_body.length; i++)
{
   if(formatted_email_body.indexOf(email_body[i]) == -1) // If not in the new array
       formatted_email_body.push(email_body[i]); // Push it
}
```

Now `formatted_email_body` is an array with only unique values.

Comment: for some reason, the `.indexOf()` does not search the email or does not find the string within the string.  When I log the `formatted_email_body` it shows me all of the emails with the full strings

Comment: Yes, that's in the fiddle and also in the json object that I've linked in the OP http://jsfiddle.net/exdjumqm/.

Comment: But in this http://412webdesigns.com/uploads/emails.json there is no duplicate emails.. what you want to remove..

Comment: The end of the second and fourth email contains the entire body of the first email,  I'd like to be able to remove that part of the email from the second and fourth

Comment: I think they are different, I think i am not getting what you want to achieve.. can you paste the two similiar strings clearly here?

Comment: Got it.. So you want to remove the same text from the second one?

Comment: Yes, and sort of, I want to remove the same text from ALL of the emails - Think of an email chain, if each person keeps hitting "reply", each email will be sort of attached to the last email.  I'd like to iterate through each email removing the subsequent duplicate text.

Comment: But still there is slight difference in first it is `can't wait to see\r\n` and in the second on it is `can't wait to see  \r\n`, which will be a significant difference to ignore it to match.

Comment: very nice catch.  It seems I need to remove all of the line breaks and spaces to really do this correctly, though then I can't get the formatting

Comment: Indeed, and for this to achieve you need to find a pattern which you can use to break a single string of email (storing several emails and replies.) Can you tell me that/

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem is so diluted, I wanted to just give an answer that is working for me for now...

I've gone back to the php and used some "rules" to cut down on the email garbage.  Here are the rules if anyone is interested:

```
//Get your email
$email = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 1.1, FT_UID); //check body types
if($email == "") $email = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_id, 1, FT_UID);// check body types
if(imap_base64($email)) $email = imap_base64($email);//decode base64 if it is
$email = quoted_printable_decode($email); //Decode the Email
$email = explode("\r\n\r\nOn", $email); //split the email if the reply starts with "On this day, this person wrote"
$email = explode("\r\n>", $email[0]); //Split the email again if the line starts with a line break and "less than" sign (>) which usually denotes a reply 
$email = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '<br />', $email[0]); //Give normal line breaks to double carriage returns and newlines
$email = str_replace("\r", ' ', $email); //Give spaces to unused carriage returns
echo $email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I've put together a function uniqParagraphs. Hope you find it useful :)

```
arr = ["Thanks so much name! We had a great time today too and can't wait to see\r\nwhat the pictures look like! Looking forward to seeing them when you're all\r\ndone editing! Thanks again :)\r\n","Hi name!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThank you for the email! You don't have to wait any further!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nWe were able to get around 70 pictures that we think were noteworthy! To  \r\ndownload ALL of your pictures, head to www.site.com\/download  \r\nand use the password \"AN5k9W\". This should automatically start your  \r\ndownload, so check your downloads folder. It's a half of a gig, so the file  \r\nis pretty large!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTo check out some of the pics while you're waiting on the download, head to  \r\nhttp:\/\/site.com\/#\/151108-name_name-engagement or  \r\nfacebook.com\/site. Remember to like us and share your pics  \r\nwith anyone you want!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nLet us know what you think!\r\n\r\nWe look forward to henameng from you!\r\n\r\nname & name\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nOn Sun, Nov 8, 2015 at 2:52 PM name name <name@gmail.com>  \r\nwrote:\r\n\r\n\r\nThanks so much name! We had a great time today too and can't wait to see  \r\nwhat the pictures look like! Looking forward to seeing them when you're all  \r\ndone editing! Thanks again :)\r\n\r\n","name and name,\r\nWe LOVE them!!  We can't thank you guys enough!  I definitely think we're\r\nready to talk wedding prices! :)\r\n\r\nname\r\n\r\nOn Wed, Nov 11, 2015 at 6:52 PM, Grealish Photography <\r\nus@site.com> wrote:\r\n\r\n","Great name!! We're so happy you love them! And thank you for being such  \r\ngreat models!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nWe have you penciled in for September 24th, 2016 so far. To get it booked  \r\npermanently, we should schedule a time for us to sit down together and have  \r\na pre-wedding consultation. During the pre-wedding consultation, we'll go  \r\nover any details you may have for the wedding, go over the contract and  \r\nthen exchange the deposit. The deposit will be 50% of the full cost of our  \r\nservices.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTo figure out the cost, I'll just need you to let me know how much time you  \r\nneed us for and where the wedding is located. This will determine the cost  \r\nand the deposit.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTo break down our pricing, we charge for our time at the event, time  \r\nediting (it's about 1:1, wedding:editing), and our time traveling. So a 6  \r\nhour wedding with 1 hour of travel time is actually 13 hours of work on our  \r\nend.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nLet me know what you think and how much time you're thinking for your  \r\nwedding (as well as where it's located) and I can give you a final price!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nWe look forward to henameng from you!\r\n\r\nname & name\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nOn Wed, Nov 11, 2015 at 10:09 PM name name <name@gmail.com>  \r\nwrote:\r\n\r\n\r\nname and name,\r\nWe LOVE them!! We can't thank you guys enough! I definitely think we're  \r\nready to talk wedding prices! :)\r\n\r\n\r\nname\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nOn Wed, Nov 11, 2015 at 6:52 PM, Grealish Photography  \r\n<us@site.com> wrote:\r\n\r\n\r\nHi name!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThank you for the email! You don't have to wait any further!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nWe were able to get around 70 pictures that we think were noteworthy! To  \r\ndownload ALL of your pictures, head to www.site.com\/download  \r\nand use the password \"AN5k9W\". This should automatically start your  \r\ndownload, so check your downloads folder. It's a half of a gig, so the file  \r\nis pretty large!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTo check out some of the pics while you're waiting on the download, head to  \r\nhttp:\/\/site.com\/#\/151108-name_name-engagement or  \r\nfacebook.com\/site. Remember to like us and share your pics  \r\nwith anyone you want!\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nLet us know what you think!\r\n\r\nWe look forward to henameng from you!\r\n\r\nname & name\r\n\r\n\r\nOn Sun, Nov 8, 2015 at 2:52 PM name name <name@gmail.com>  \r\nwrote:\r\n\r\n\r\nThanks so much name! We had a great time today too and can't wait to see  \r\nwhat the pictures look like! Looking forward to seeing them when you're all  \r\ndone editing! Thanks again :)\r\n\r\n\r\n"]
uniq = {};
uniqParagraphs = function(e) {
  $a = e.match( /[^\r\n]+[\r\n\r\n]+/g ); // split into paragraphs

  $($a).each( function (index, sentence) {
    // calc one way hash for trim'ed text
    // these are smaller uniq values for large texts
    key = calcMD5(sentence.trim());
    // else use a very large key too
    // key = sentence.trim();
    if (uniq[key] !== undefined) { // if para already exists, remove it
      $a[index] = "";
    } else {
      uniq[key] = true; // add para to uniq dictionary
    }
  });

  return $a.join(""); // join everything again
}

$(arr).each( function(i, e) {
  arr[i] = uniqParagraphs(e); // update arr[i]
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle, in case: http://jsfiddle.net/exdjumqm/1/